# Pass php variable to jquery script is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following jquery script:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".clickable").click(function () {
                $(this).animate({left: '1030px'}, function () {
                    $(this).fadeOut("slow", function () {
                        document.location.href = $(this).get(0).id + ".php";
                    });
                });
            });

        });
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Chi").animate({left: '0'}, {duration: 200, queue: false});
            $("#Dove").animate({left: '0'}, {duration: 400, queue: false});
            $("#Quando").animate({left: '0'}, {duration: 600, queue: false});
            $("#Cosa").animate({left: '0'}, {duration: 800, queue: false});
            var phpvariable=<? echo $row; ?>
            $('.dreams-photo-profile-mydream').css({"background": "url(\"/images/user.png\")"});
            $('.dreams-photo-profile-mydream').css({"background-repeat": "no-repeat"});
            $('.dreams-photo-profile-mydream').css({"background-position": "center"});
            $('.dreams-photo-profile-mydream').css({"background-size": "contain"});

        });

    </script>
```

And i'm trying to pass a php variable like so:

```
   <?php
    $gdb->connettiDB();
    $row = $gdb->getFotoProfilo(getId());
    ?>

 var phpvariable=<? echo $row; ?>
```

That 's not working. When i declare a var inside the script, everything seems blocked and my animations aren't working and I don't know why. Can anyone explain me how can I exactly do that?

Comment: Can you show us what does your `getFotoProfilo()` function makes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong use of php:-

```
var phpvariable=<? echo $row; ?>
```

It should be

```
 var your_variable='<?php echo $row; ?>';
```

Comment: It depends on whether `$row` is a string or number.

Comment: You don't know what `getFotoProfilo()` function returns.

Comment: You could build a <input type="hidden" name="myRow" value="<?php echo $row ?>"> and reference that later in the js.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to pass variables from php to javascript, is to use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
var phpvariable=<?php echo json_encode($row); ?>;
```

Now the php will not accidentally break your javascript regardless of the type of variable that is `$row`. And the name suggests something like an array...

If `$row` is an integer, the problem could also have been caused by a missing short-tag setting in php. That's why I have used `<?php` in my example.

Lastly, a missing `;` after your variable declaration in javascript, could also cause problems but that would depend on what comes after it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the html containing the `<script>` you've posted above is in the same file. The `$row` variable needs to be defined before the `<script>`.

You are also missing a `;` at the end of the javascript line

```
var phpvariable=<? echo $row; ?>;
```

If `$row` is a string, you also need to use `"`:

```
var phpvariable="<? echo $row; ?>";
```

Comment: `;` is optional before `?>`

Comment: @Barmar sure, but I meant at the end of the JS line - edited for clarity

Comment: Javascript will also insert semicolons at the end of line when necessary. http://www.codecademy.com/blog/78-your-guide-to-semicolons-in-javascript

Comment: Note that I'm not recommending leaving out the semicolon, just saying that it's not the cause of the problem.

Comment: @Barmar Point taken, but it's not exactly a safe practice, and we may as well advocate a good coding style

Comment: Of course. Just suggesting that you distinguish suggestions from solutions to the problem.

Comment: BTW, I recommend `var phpvariable = <? echo json_encode($row); ?>;` That will handle any data type that can be passed from PHP to JS.

Comment: @Barmar ah yes, jeroen's answer is better.