# JQuery function fails when php variable inserted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Have a very simple JQuery function that replaces data in an HTML span tag when the word "...more" is clicked.  It's purpose is to add more text to the end of an article:

```
<span id="more" style = "color: blue; cursor:pointer;">...more</span>
<script>
//To get remainder of article when clicked on "...more"
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#more").click(function(){ 
                   $("#more").text('<?php echo $fullArticle; ?>');
                   $("#more").css('color','black');
                   $("#more").css('cursor','');
        });
    });
</script>
```

This does not work when I insert the php variable.  When I click, there is no change.  When I use a text string like `$("#more").text('some data');` in place of the PHP variable, the script works fine, replacement happens. The articles I have read seem to indicate this is the proper way to pass php variables into JQuery functions, but I must be missing something.

EDIT:  typical content of $fullArticle:

```
<div>
<h2>Why do we use it?</h2>
<p>It is a long  to using 'Content here, content here', 
    making it look like readable English.</p><p> Many desktop publishing packages and 
   web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search 
   for 'lorem ipsum' will e years, sometimes by accident, 
   sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).<img style="float: 
   left; margin: 10px;" title="DSC00286.JPG" src="images/images91/imageID11424.jpg" 
   alt="" width="200" height="154" /></p>
</div>
<div>
<h2>Where does it come from?</h2>
```

These articles are user generated and the resultant output varies as to what is created each time.

Comment: Its very likely that the $fullArticle variable contains one or more quotes or slashes. can you do <?php echo str_replace(["'","\"],["\'","\\"],$fullArticle; ?> and tell me the result

Comment: Open source code. You will see what is wrong. Obviously that you have quotes in text that break js code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass php variable to jquery script is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29864630/pass-php-variable-to-jquery-script-is-not-working)

Comment: Escape the PHP variable as @peshraw suggested. [addslashes](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) might be useful for this.

Comment: @Peshraw.  Yes, the $fullArticle is HTML scripted content which will contain quotes and slashes, etc. - so this is my problem.  Thought you were just missing a bracket on your str_replace, so I tried `<?php echo str_replace(["'","\"],["\'","\\"],$fullArticle); ?>`, but am getting a syntax error: `unexpected \ after String '"\"],["' (...plus a bunch of other stuff).  Can you point me to any articles that discuss these issues of disallowed characters? I will update my question to include the typical contents of $fullArticle.

Comment: I didn't know that there is a function in php like addslashes(). Thanks to @spoofie. can you try echo addslashes ( $fullArticle ) and tell us the result?
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Comment: @Peshraw. Tried addslashes and htmlspecialchars and when I echo straight to the browser, the rendering is not quite as the original.  Both failed to source the image properly, the addslashes caused some '\' to show up, the htmlspecialchars caused many html code objects to show up... AND both caused the "...more" to do nothing when I clicked on it, so it seems like the Javascript did not like either, even though inspecting the source it seems like all quotes got escaped (for addslashes) and all special characters got converted (htmlspecialchars)...

Comment: is there a different  type spec I can use instead of ".text" that allows taking the raw data without problems?  `$("#more").text('<?php echo $fullArticle; ?>');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Let full article be

```
<?php $fullArticle="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem possimus, iusto, ea minus facilis commodi magnam similique nam aspernatur eaque, sequi nemo perspiciatis quasi aperiam recusandae enim quae reiciendis error?";?>
```

Your html code be

```
<span id="more" style = "color: blue; cursor:pointer;">...more</span>
<button id="more">More</button>
```

Your script,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("button#more").click(function(){ 
        var fullArticle = "<?=$fullArticle;?>";
                   $("#more").text(fullArticle);
                   $("#more").css('color','red');
                   // $("#more").css('cursor','');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Things possibly went wrong...

1. **First Possibility**

The PHP variable `$fullArticle;` might hold an ambiguous data, a data that might contain a **single quote** or a **double quote** or something else that might contradict with jquery syntax.

> Why this doubt? Coz when u entered normal text, desired output was achieved so the syntactical problem should be caused by stored data.

2. Try checking for PHP Error.

`UBUNTU users : sudo tailf /var/log/apache2/error.log
OR 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

> Why this doubt? Coz Error might have arised while assigning data into a variable that you've used into jquery.

Answer (score 0):

The line returns and tabs in the $fullArticle was causing problems.  The following change in code using the html specifier and backticks`` instead of quotes''  resolved the issue:

```
$("#more").html(`<?php echo $fullArticle; ?>`);
```

Could also have deleted the line return and tab characters in $fullArticle and kept using the quotes by using:

```
$fullArticle = preg_replace('/[\n\r\t]/', '', $fullArticle);
```

For a clearer example of the issue, you can view [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50579063/hidden-characters-causing-jquery-function-to-fail/50579163?noredirect=1#comment88170807_50579163).