# Hidden characters causing JQuery function to fail

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to understand what causes a simple jquery function to fail.  It simply looks for the ID, replaces some content with other data.  I have $data1, $data2, $data3 as the replacement test data for "...more".  The replace works for $data1 and $data2, but fails for $data3.  Unfortunately, all of the data I need to work with comes in $data3 format.

The test code is below:

```
<?php
  $data1 = '<p>line one text here</p>'; 
  $data2 = '<p>line one text here</p><p>line two text here</p><p>line three text here</p>';
  $data3 = <<<EOF
    <p>line one text here</p>
    <p>line two text here</p>
    <p>line tgree text here</p>
EOF;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            //To get remainder of article when clicked on "...more"
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#more").click(function () {
                    $("#more").html('<?= $data2; ?>');
                    $("#more").css('color', 'black');
                    $("#more").css('cursor', '');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="card-text"><span id="more" style = "color: blue; cursor:pointer;">...more</span></p>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Looking at the console, I see that the data in the jquery code shows single continuous lines for $data1 and $data2, however, for $data3, there are clearly line breaks which is what I am suspecting is causing the failure (script does nothing, no change-out occurs).  See graphic below:

[image]

How would I find out what these hidden characters are that are creating the problem so that I can remove/replace all of them before submitting to the jquery function, or is there a way to process it in the function beforehand?  Any other insight is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: PS: all your script are better placed right before the closing `</body>` tag. (not in the HEAD of your document in a render-blocking manner)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix this you will either need to use template literals in your JS code, ie. delimit the string with `` ` `` instead of `'` or `"`. This is because they allow line breaks within the string literal, as PHP does:

```
$("#more").html(`<?= $data2; ?>`);
```

Note that this is unsupported in IE11 and lower.

Alternatively you will need to replace the line breaks in the string in PHP before it's output to the JS.

Comment: Your suggestion worked great!  Am I to understand that using the backticks ` ` means the jquery script will accept the all the characters and hence also replace all the characters?  Seems to be.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

EOF is adding return carriages and tabs chars to your string.

You can change your PHP way of creating $data3 :

```
<?php
  $data1 = '<p>line one text here</p>'; 
  $data2 = '<p>line one text here</p><p>line two text here</p><p>line three text here</p>';
  $data3 =
    "<p>line one text here</p>"
    . "<p>line two text here</p>"
    . "<p>line tgree text here</p>";
?>
```

you can also replace unwanted values :

```
$data3 = preg_replace('/[\n\r\t]/', '', $data3);
```